# How to set and use a "global param" in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an application where the user modifies an object at a time, and this object have multiple child objects. What I need is to place the id, or any other identifier, as a global param in the URL, for exemple:

`mysite.com/:budget_id/accounts`

`mysite.com/:budget_id/payess`

And starting from this point I can get this `budget_id`in the application controller or any other place I need.

Any suggestion on how doing this on the `routes.rb` file, or any other approach?

Comment: "global param"? Why not use a session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use a scope.

In routes.rb:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "/(:budget_id)", defaults: {budget_id: "1"} do
    ...
  end
end
```